# Paginator and Select with join

Tags: select, zend-framework, pagination, zend-framework2, zend-paginator

In my current ZF2 projet, I use Paginator but I have a encorred a problem.

When I use Paginator with a select join, I can't display the object element who don't belong at my Servicegroup object.

```
# Create a new Select object
      $Select = new Select();
      $Select->from('t_service_group')
             ->join('t_user_group', 't_user_group.user_group_id = t_service_group.fk_user_group_id')
             ->order('service_group_name ASC');

      # Create a new result set
      $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
      $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new ServiceGroup());

      # Create a new pagination adapter object
      $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect(
        # Our configured select object
        $Select,
        # The adapter to run it against
        $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(),
        # The result set to hydrate
        $resultSetPrototype
      );
      $paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
      return $paginator;
```

Do you know how I can do to use paginator without using:

```
 setArrayObjectPrototype(new ServiceGroup());
```

Thanks you all for your help
Best regards

**EDIT**

If you use a select query with join in your query paginator. You have to make that:

```
     # Create a new Select object
      $Select = new Select();
      $Select->from('t_service_group')
             ->join('t_user_group', 't_user_group.user_group_id = t_service_group.fk_user_group_id')
             ->order('service_group_name ASC');

      # Create a new result set
      $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
#      $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new ServiceGroup());

      # Create a new pagination adapter object
      $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect(
        # Our configured select object
        $Select,
        # The adapter to run it against
        $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(),
        # The result set to hydrate
        $resultSetPrototype
      );
      $paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
      return $paginator;
```

Answer (score 0):

You simple don't set a resultsetprototype and let use the default result set prototype which will populate all the values returning from the row